# Term for bad press release

Tags: expressions

A press release is a written or recorded communication directed at members of the news media for the purpose of announcing something newsworthy.

However, is there a term for bad press release? Something, which an organization would use for communicating something gone wrong?

Comment: A press release is a press release. You could however qualify it according to circumstance, such as 'emergency press release' or describe it differently, for example: 'customer safety information'

Comment: In my line of trade this is called a "failure notice".

Comment: @Reg That's more like what I was looking for. Can you post that as an answer with more details?

Comment: No, mu, there is not. By any stretch of your imagination *press release* here has the same *definitive* or *necessary* meaning as *paragraph/phrase/sentence/word…* You seem to be confusing *judgement/value* which could mean whatever you want, with *evidence/fact* which are rather different, are they not?

Comment: Well, generally speaking it's going to attempt to *whitewash* the information.

Comment: It's called *consumer notification*. It is a well established legal idea and there are many regulations requiring companies to notify consumers of things I'm sure they would prefer to keep quiet about - such as identity theft, toxic spills, product safety issues, conflicts of interest, etc.

Comment: @PhilSweet Thanks. Please post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry, Guys: whatever Phil Sweet thought "consumer notification" meant, it doesn't mean "bad press release" any more than Hot Licks' "whitewash." Depending solely on your point of view, anything fitting either description could be a dreadful, a good or the best-ever press release.

That there is no specific term for a bad press release, nor anything like it, is part of the justification for the infamous "There's no such thing as bad publicity."

Generic terms might include "cock up" or "slip up" or simply "mistake" but none has to do with the press in particular, nor any kind of release.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The infamous 'There's no such thing as bad publicity' is plainly untrue.  Though Phil Sweet is correct to some degree, a consumer notification is more on the legal/consumer side rather than press facing (so not a direct equivalent of press release).  A "Slip up" or similar phrases would refer to something that would require the company to release a crisis statement to begin with.

Comment: Of course, Balaz2ta. Did you think I meant something other than that 'There's no such thing as bad publicity' is plainly untrue? Sorry I put it so poorly.

If you think a consumer notification is more on the legal/consumer side rather than press facing (so not a direct equivalent of press release) doubtless you'll be able to explain how…

Don't let's even play with your "slip up…"

Answer (score 2):

In the industry, this would be referred to as *crisis communications*

From [Wikkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_communication):

> Crisis communication is a sub-specialty of the public relations
>   profession that is designed to protect and defend an individual,
>   company, or organization facing a public challenge to its reputation

Example:

> After our products were found to spontaneously explode, we had to
>   engage in crisis communications.

Furthermore, the communication itself could be referred to as a crisis statement, or simply a statement. Sometimes it can also be called a holding statement.

> The company released a crisis statement after their products began
>   exploding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any specific word / term that organizations use for this, but possibly something along the lines of *public relations failing*?

> > **CEO:** We've had some backlash from the press?
> >
> > **Employee:** Yes, the PR has phrased the release wrong and had an iffy headline.

Think something would go along like this possibly. I can't find any other alternative. Let me know when you find an answer of if this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I don’t think this is what mu is asking about. “Bad press release” is not intended to mean “press release of poor quality”, but “press release about a negative incident”, like the BP Oil press releases about the oil spill a few years ago, for instance, or Apple’s press release about Steve Jobs’ death. Not that that changes the essential answer here: there is no specific word for such a thing to my knowledge, either.

Comment: In Politics, people float balloons. Sometimes the balloons float, but when not well received, they sink and are called "lead balloons"